# What's wrong with my discordpy get() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I want to write a funny little discord bot that's in a russian theme. I want to make it play the USSR Anthem no matter what song is requested, in the channel that's written after "&channel" in the command on discord.

This is the console feed I get, when I type "vadim play something &channel Just Chatting blyat:

Privet
Just Chatting
Ignoring exception in on_menter code hereessage
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\maria\Desktop\Coding\Projekte\Python\SovjetBot\Code\bot.py", line 33, in on_message
voicechannel = channel.connect()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connect'

Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
import time


class MyClient(discord.Client):

    #Triggered on login
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Privet")
    #Triggered on messages
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.content.lower().startswith("vadim") and message.content.lower().endswith("blyat"):
            messagearray = message.content.split(" ")
            messagearray.pop()
            messagearray.remove("vadim")

            if messagearray[0].lower() == "play" and ((len(messagearray)) != 1 or messagearray.contains('&channel')):

                where = ""
                for i in range(messagearray.index("&channel") + 1, len(messagearray)):
                    where = where + ' ' + messagearray[i]
                    where = where[0:]
                    time.sleep(0.25)

                print(where)

                channel = get(message.guild.channels, name=where)
                time.sleep(0.25)
                voicechannel = channel.connect()
                time.sleep(0.25)
                voicechannel.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('National Anthem of USSR.mp3'))








client = MyClient()
client.run(The bots client id)
```

Answer (score 0):

### TLDR

Change

```
channel = get(message.guild.channels, name=where)
```

To

```
channel = await get(message.guild.channels, name=where)
```

### Explanation

There error indicates you have an issue on the line `voicechannel = channel.connect()` because `channel` is `NoneType`. You define `channel` on the line above with `channel = get(message.guild.channels, name=where)`. However, according to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.AsyncIterator.get) the `get()` function you're using is a coroutine so you need to `await` it.

### Side Note

After you create `channel`, you should check that it's not `None` before you try to use it with `voicechannel = channel.connect()`.